# Regex returns string undefined

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I am trying to extract hash value from an magnet link but it returns *undefined*

```
var tesst = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:2B78EDFDDC87DC9605FB285997A80B787888C194&"
var test = tesst.match(/magnet:\?xt=urn:btih:[a-z\d]{40}\&/im);
alert (test[1]);
```

I cant understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You dont have any capture groups in regex. Use `test[0]` to print entire match

Comment: put `test[0]` instead of `test[1]`... because there isn't a capturing group.

Comment: `test[0]` prints whole string i.e `tesst` value

Comment: @user3452098 that is what we are asking. Which value in particular do you want?

Comment: I want **2B78EDFDDC87DC9605FB285997A80B787888C194**

Comment: @user3452098 - Use https://regex101.com/#javascript to test and understand your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just mark what you want with capturing group:

```
/^magnet:\?xt=urn:btih:([a-z\d]{40})\&$/im
```

Also I recomend to not use regexp here.
Try followed:

```
tesst.split(':')[3].slice(0, -1);
```

`slice(0, -1)` used for remove last '&', you can use any other method, like `slice(0, 40)`, `replace(/[^\w]/g, '')` or any other.

Comment: regex also helps me extract hash only if its an magnet link anyways thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = tesst.match(/magnet:\?xt=urn:btih:([a-z\d]{40})\&/im);
```

You forgot the ( ) around the hash part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `[a-z\d]{40}` part inside a  capturing group and you don't need to escape `&` symbol, because it isn't a regex meta character.

```
> var test = tesst.match(/magnet:\?xt=urn:btih:([a-z\d]{40})&/im);
undefined
> console.log(test[1])
2B78EDFDDC87DC9605FB285997A80B787888C194
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
/([^:]+)&$/
```

and use `test[1]`

```
console.log(str.match(/([^:]+)&$/)[1]);
```